# What was the first SciFi work that had a "biologically different" intelligent race?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre

What was the first SciFi work that had a an intelligent race that was biologically significantly different from humans?

Not simply "non humanoid", but, say, non-vertebrate (non-humanoid vertebrates are OK, as long as they are clearly non-humanoid). In other words, intelligent octopi or better yet aliens like bacteria or insects; these are what I'm interested in, but intelligent cats – like Kzinti who are fairly humanoid – are not.

A "race" means there's a whole large population of biologically similar beings. One-off intelligent monsters like Cthulu or Godzilla aren't what I'm asking about.

Comment: ...has *anyone* concocted an **intelligent** bacterial race?

Comment: @GorchestopherH - Yes. several times. Feel free to ask for the earliest example - I know of at least 2 (one is Sector General series)

Comment: Greg Bear, in Blood Music and later in Vitals. In Vitals, they're natural and have been here since the beginning of life on the planet.

Comment: @DVK Wow, given that bacteria are single-cell organisms without even a nucleus, I would have never imagined someone concocting a story where they are intelligent.

Comment: @GorchestopherH:   And what about the midichlorians?! They have some sort of mass intelligence.  :/   (Yes, I'm being totally sarcastic.)

Comment: DVK - "A "race" means there's a whole large population of biologically similar beings. One-off intelligent monsters like Chthulu or Godzilla aren't what I'm asking about."  see below.

Comment: DVK - "A "race" means there's a whole large population of biologically similar beings. One-off intelligent monsters like Chthulu or Godzilla aren't what I'm asking about."  At the Mountains of Madness in the 1930s mentions the Spawn of Cthulhu, octopus-shaped invaders from another world and possibly another dimension - though too late to be the first exotic aliens.

Comment: @GorchestopherH there's even an intelligent virus in _Red Dwarf_.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would like to humbly challenge the accepted answer. [Gulliver's Travels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulliver%27s_Travels), written in **1726** features intelligent horses living on an undiscovered island (human-level or maybe even slightly higher intelligence).

While they are mammals, they are not human-like, so I think it does not fall into the furry cats-people exception the QA stated.

<sub>(If we counted folk tales, legends, etc, we could find earlier examples: talking, intelligent lizards, or talking ants and grasshoppers from Aesop's fables, but we don't classify them as sci-fi. Gulliver's Travels is however a clear sci-fi, even if the term was not used in this form at that time, just look at the description of Laputa)</sub>

Comment: Hm... I'm a bit ambivalent on whether GT is sci-fi - I personally would classify them as more of a fable. Would you mind asking if it is SciFi on meta? If the consensus on meta is that it's SF, I'll change the accept to this answer as it's clearly earlier. +1

Comment: @DVK: Wikipedia says it's a proto sci-fi. My opinion is, that if it contained only the first two books (the lands of the size/12 and size*12 people) which are often retold as children's stories, it would not really be a sci-fi. The last two books however, are somewhat different. I posted a question about it on meta, feel free to edit or comment it. http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2111/does-a-story-which-is-older-than-the-term-sci-fi-but-does-contain-features-co

Comment: To be honest, the latter part of your meta question changed my mind, so I won't even need to wait for meta answers.

Comment: I have no issue with calling this sci-fi :) Although the distinction between cats and horses seems rather slight - you were asking for  "non-vertebrate. In other words, intelligent Octopii or better yet aliens like bacteria or insects". You may want to clarify in your question.

Comment: The date that the genre was coined has nothing at all to do with what belongs under its umbrella. For example, the word "cat" has not been around as long as cats have.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: I assume the example with the cat-people was not about the "cat" part but about the anthropomorphism: furry cat-people who look more like humans with cat-ears than cats.

Comment: @MarkBeadles - Sorry, that was bad writing on my part in the Q. The problem with Kzinti is not that they are cats - it's that they are cat-originated very-close-to-humanoid. A horse on the other hand is very much NON-humanoid, vertebrae and all

Comment: @DVK Gotcha, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 16):

[*The War of the Worlds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds) (1898) is an early work, and the [Martian Invaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_%28The_War_of_the_Worlds%29) were biologically different: octopoid and unusually susceptible to Earth bacteria.  [Prior to that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars/Mars_in_fiction#First_ventures), Martians were not noted as biologically different but rather just as human, or smaller, etc.

Comment: Weird. For some weird reason I was 100% certain when asking that Wells' Martians were humanoid and expected that to NOT be the answer. Shoulda checked :)

Comment: WotW is often an answer to ["Earliest X in Sci-Fi"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12521/3804)...except when it isn't

Comment: Predating *War of the Worlds* is *Les Xipehuz [The Shapes]* by [J.-H. Rosny aîné](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J.-H._Rosny_aîné), featuring aliens that looked like geometric solids, who visited Earth in prehistoric times.

Comment: The book I mentioned above was from 1887, BTW. And [this article](http://www.astrobio.net/amee/March/retrospections.htm) mentions that Camille Flammarion published three stories in 1873 featuring a disembodied spirit who "observes the potential range of wondrously exotic life in the universe". It also says that in one of the stories, *Lumen*, "Flammarion was the first author to thoroughly apply the theory of evolution, albeit Lamarckian, to the creation of truly alien life forms".

Answer (score 3):

May not be first but is certainly early - The Selenites inhabiting the Moon in the film  Le Voyage dans la Lune (1902) appear to be humanoid ants.